# Erro ao instalar eclipse: Exit Code: 13

Tags: java, linux, java-ee, eclipse

Olá!

Estou tentando instalar o eclipse no ubuntu XFCE 18.04, com o openjdk8 instalado e com o path configurado em "/etc/profile":
[image: /etc/profile]

Porém continua dando o exit code 13:
[image: exit code 13]

Eu não me recordo muito bem se no passado eu alterei o PATH em algum outro lugar, que está mostrando nessa imagem um path diferente do atual. Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Seu eclipse está apontano para a versão java-oracle, olhe a linha:

```
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle//bin/java
-vmargs
```

O caminho no path pelo que entendi na sua duvida, deveria ser o do openjdk..

Execute um:`java -version` e post o que mostra no console

Comment: O resultado ficou:
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: pensando aqui.. remova essa linha: -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-oracle//bin/java e veja se sobe